# On which day in October are US student payments due?

Tags: united-states, student-loan, covid-19

Media says payments are due to restart in October. But when?

Comment: Your question needs a lot more detail. What media? Can you link to an article? What payments are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Media says payments are due to restart in October. But when?

The short answer is it depends.

According to [Student aid.gov](https://studentaid.gov/announcements-events/covid-19/payment-pause-zero-interest):

> Congress recently passed a law preventing further extensions of the
> payment pause. Student loan interest will resume starting on Sept. 1,
> 2023, and payments will be due starting in October. We will notify
> borrowers well before payments restart.

Ob the same site but looking at the [Prepare for Student Loan Payments To Restart](https://studentaid.gov/manage-loans/repayment/prepare-payments-restart) page

> **What do I need to know?**
>
> - Your first payment will be due in October 2023. You’ll get your bill, with your payment amount and due date, at least 21 days before
>   your due date.
> - Don’t wait until you get your first bill to start preparing.

a little farther down the same page:

> **Find out what your monthly payment amount will be.**
>
> When: August or September
>
> Your monthly bill in September will contain your payment amount. You
> also may receive a communication called a “disclosure” from your
> servicer as early as August, letting you know what your monthly
> payment will be.
>
> You’ll be able to visit your account on your servicer’s website to see
> your payment amount once your disclosure or bill has been sent. [Log in
> to find your servicer](https://studentaid.gov/fsa-id/sign-in/landing/?redirectTo=/aid-summary/servicers-and-schools).

Comment: Thanks!
so the lender is eligible to start collecting in Oct, on and day it wishes?
That would promote setting due dates to earlier during the month, no?

Comment: My guess is that the schedule is the same as before payments were suspended. So if your payment used to be due on the 15th of every month, the first payment will be due Oct 15. @BlackNinja